# Reduce memory usage with stringdistmatrix

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, out-of-memory, stringdist

I have a `data.table` ***dt*** of 9k rows (see sample below). I need to compare each ***rname*** of ***dt*** to each ***cname*** of a reference `data.table` ***dt.ref***. By comparing, I mean computing the Levenshtein ratio.

Then, I take the maximum and get my output (see below).

dt

```
nid | rname  | maxr
n1  | apple  |  0.5
n2  | pear   |  0.8
n3  | banana |  0.7
n4  | kiwi   |  0.6
... (9k)
```

dt.ref

```
cid | cname
c1  | apple
c2  | maple
c3  | peer
c4  | dear
c5  | bonobo
c6  | kiwis
... (75k)
```

output

```
nid | rname  | maxr | maxLr | cid
n1  | apple  |  0.5 | 1     | c1
n2  | pear   |  0.8 | 0.75  | c3
n2  | pear   |  0.8 | 0.75  | c4
n3  | banana |  0.7 | 0.33  | c5
n4  | kiwi   |  0.6 | 0.8   | c6
...
```

To compute this output, I use the `stringdistmatrix` function inside a function coded this way (see [Computing the Levenshtein ratio of each element of a data.table with each value of a reference table and merge with maximum ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565596/computing-the-levenshtein-ratio-of-each-element-of-a-data-table-with-each-value/45566230?noredirect=1#comment78135972_45566230)):

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  require(stringdist)
  require(matrixStats)
  dis  <- stringdistmatrix(x, y, method = "lv")
  mat <- sapply(nchar(y), function(i) pmax(i, nchar(x)))
  r <- 1 - dis / mat
  w <- apply(r, 1, function(x) which(x==max(x)))
  m <- rowMaxs(r)
  list(m = m, w = w)
}

r <- f1(dt[[2]], dt.ref[[2]])
dt[, maxLr := r$m ]
dtnew <- dt[rep(1:.N, lengths(r$w)),]
dtnew[, cid := dt.ref[unlist(r$w), 1]]
```

However, with a 9k x 75k matrix, I have a memory issue that makes the R session abort. Beyond splitting up the 9k table, would it be a way to:

1. code differently using only `data.table` and not a matrix?
2. sort and split the reference table to compute the Levenshtein ratio only on a subset of the 75k strings?

Comment: maybe add a link to previous question, for additional information..

Comment: has this been solved? i'm having the same issues